# How to Retrieve either Top N rows OR all rows from a table in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a `datagridview` in which a user is allowed to retriev either `n` records (using textbox)  or All records by clicking on a `buttun`

Now want to retrieve `Top N` records Or All Records with a single Query.
right now I'm using  2 different Queries to achieve.

```
//retrieving Top N Records
 SELECT Top @Rows FROM CaseDetails //@Row is parameter
```

And

```
 //retrieving All records
SELECT Top (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CaseDetails) FROM CaseDetails
```

How can i Use a single query in `SQL Server` to perform these 2 options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is working fine**

Declare parameters

```
Create Procedure uspRetrieve
@Rows int =NULL
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SET ROWCOUNT @Rows
   SELECT * FROM CaseDetails
End
```

IF you supply @Row=0 you will get all records else you get @Row =your limit

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky one.

Really you'd probably pass `@Rows` in all cases, or `NULL` to select all rows, then null coalesce via `ISNULL` to select the count from the table to get all rows.

```
// Set the Rows param first
SELECT @Rows = ISNULL(@Rows, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CaseDetails))

// @Rows is parameter
SELECT TOP @Rows * FROM CaseDetails
```

Comment: Not working. Its giving following error
`Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'.`
`Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

Comment: Ahh I'm not near a PC/IDE to test. Maybe won't allow literals. Let me adjust my answer.

Comment: The last statement needs to be: `SELECT TOP (@Rows) * `

Answer (score 2):

I think you better off by creating a procedure like

```
create procedure sp_fetch 
@row int = NULL
as
begin
if @row = 0 or @row is null
SELECT * FROM CaseDetails
else
select top @row * from CaseDetails
end
```

Then you can just call your procedure like

```
exec sp_fetch(10)
```

Comment: actually my stored procedure have a large number of columns (apx. 20) and '`join` to many table. I want to know that if I'm writing `SELECT` statement twice i.e inside `IF` and inside `Else` so should I have too writing all Columns twice. ??

Comment: @SeaSharp, Not sure I understood you correctly but I would vouch for creating a SP rather going for a TSQL. You can even call this SP inside your main SP and call it from your front end app as well.

Comment: @SeaSharp, yes; as can be seen in my answer. You will have to write the query twice once in IF and another in ELSE. But if your query is BIG then you can create a CTE and use that CTE inside IF .. ELSE. Finally, it's your decision .. whichever suits your needs best.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to count all rows before selecting.
Assuming `@Rows` is an int, then you can use the max value of an int as your default.
So, if `@Rows` is 0 or null, return all rows, otherwise, return `@Rows` rows:

```
SELECT TOP (ISNULL(NULLIF(@Rows,0), 2147483647)) * FROM CaseDetails;
```

Comment: What is that `You` link is for? Just curious.

Comment: From work, I can't post literal sql to SO, probably because of firewall rules. I once included the link to a question where someone had the same problem, and discovered that by including the link, I can post the sql. Wierd, but works. I try to make it unnoticeable, and often try to edit it out when I am home.

Comment: WTF??? LOL .. that's total wierd? I think you should post a thread in `meta.stackoverflow.com` for same and get it clarified.

Comment: Yeah got it, but that's a big HHHHAAACCCKKK :)